# Can't get Vue slider work

Tags: slider, vue.js

I need two range slider, where I can set min and max value. I found this [slider](https://github.com/lepture/vui/blob/master/src/ui/RangeSlider.vue)

It source confuse me, because it have min and max values, but when I run it I see only one movement element.

But problem that I can't understand how to track changing. Here is my code:

```
Vue.component('com', {
    props: ['value'],
    template: `
            <div class="v-range-slider">
              <slot name="left"></slot>
              <input type="range" :value.sync="value" :min="min" :max="max" :step="step" :name="name">
              <slot name="right"></slot>
            </div>
            `
  })

App = new Vue ({ 
   el: '#app',
  data: 
    {
     value: 46
    },

  watch : 
  {
    value : function(value)
    {
        console.log(this.value);
    }
  },

methods:
{

}

})

}
```

And HTML part:

```
<div id="app">
    <com></com>
    <p> Min value: {{value}}</p>
</div>
```

I tried insert code to http://jsfiddle.net/p5dox54w/ but it's not work. ON my PC it's show slider, but in console I do not see any changes when I move it's position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the `App`'s value into the child component, and add `.sync` to the property so that it will sync back up to the parent.

```
<com :value.sync="value"></com>
```

Comment: should I add it's to at `com` tag or can I can write:
`<input type="range" :value.sync="value" :min="min" :max="max" :step="step" :name="name">`.

Between I still do not see anything in console. And I can't where I am wrong. On `watch` or elsewhere

Comment: It is working here: http://jsfiddle.net/p5dox54w/2/ .  There was a misplaced bracket, not sure if that was your issue.  as for the comment, no you still want to use v-model.  `v-model` syncs the input to the `value` variable, and `.sync` sync's the child value back up to the parent

Comment: thanks! No it's working! What does min and max in example mean?

Comment: Ah sorry I left those in from your original code.  You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/p5dox54w/4/ where I passed in the other variables as well, so you can customize the slider

Comment: thanks, but it's look like min and max values just for limits. I need way to get 2 range slider like http://refreshless.com/nouislider/ is it's possible with current code?